# Sum of all possible path weights in a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for possible research directions from a problem I am working on. Graph theory isn't my field, and the only reference I have is Graph Theory by Diestel, which I started reading recently but I am not sure if the book has what I am looking for.

So I have a graph with vertices labeled 1 to n. A possible path along the graph has to have the vertices in a topological order, i.e a path $(v_0, v_1,...,v_k)$ in the graph requires that $v_0 < v_1 < ... < v_k$. Each edge has a weight, and the weight of a path is just the product of all edge weights along the path. The quality I am looking at is the sum of all possible path weights of the graph. All possible paths include paths of all possible lengths from 1 to n-1 (length of a path is just the number of edges in it). I want to know if there is a bound on this value. Is there a graph configuration that achieves a minimum just like the permanent of a matrix?

Appreciate if someone can point out possible directions for me to research further.

Edit: I realize this is a poorly formulated question without some context.

The graph comes from a stochastic matrix, so each edge weight is positive and no larger than 1. Think of the edge weight values come from half of a stochastic matrix (i.e., the upper triangular part). In addition, I would assume the stochastic matrix satisfies all convergence criteria it’s strongly connected so that all edge weights can't be 0's or 1's at the same time. When I said a bound, I didn't necessarily mean lower bound (obviously you can have very small edge weights driving the sum arbitrarily small). An upper bound would great to know. Also I am interested in knowing or proving properties of such a value so hopefully someone has encountered something similar would be able to give me some pointers.

Comment: Ae you sure that the weight of a path shall be the product of its edges, not the sum? (like e. g. in Dijkstra's algorithm)

Comment: Yes, it's the product and not the sum similar to how the permanent is computed.

Comment: You should probably add some conditions; the minimum can be achieved either by having no edges, or by having edges with very small weights.

Comment: Yes you are correct. You should assume the edge weights are positive and <= 1.

Comment: And if it comes from a stochastic matrix somehow, that means something or other sums to 1, right? Otherwise we make all the weights very tiny numbers?

Comment: I think a lower bound comes up under a different context involving this sum but that would take a lot of writing to explain.

Comment: Note that the sum over all paths can be read off quite easily from the matrix.  If $w_{ij}$ is the weight from $v_i$ to $v_j$, then the total weight from $v_0$ to $v_j$ is given recursively by $P_0 = 1$, $P_j = \sum_{i<j}  P_i w_{ij}$. This makes the product-of-weights formulation very natural.

Comment: Yes, I think the sum can be computed in $O(n^2)$ time using a dynamic programming approach despite exponential number of terms.

Comment: @serige Is there a condition that prevents there being one very heavy edge (weight $1-\epsilon$) that connects $1$ to $n$)?  Otherwise it seems like the upper bound is just $1$.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by one edge that connects 1 to n? Do you mean a path of length $n-1$ that goes through every vertex?

Comment: @serige Maybe I don’t understand the fine details of your question.  I assume it is possible for there to be an edge that connects the first vertex to the last, and that that edge can have its weight arbitrarily close to $1$.  If not, how can you have paths of length $1$?  Actually I have been assuming that you’re only counting paths that start at 1 and end at $n$, but maybe you are counting all sub paths of those paths as well (without duplication).  If so I take back my upper bound of $1$ claim, but I still think the above example is at least possible but not optimal.